# Change MDCTextField Outlined text fields' active border color

Tags: ios, swift, material-design, material-components, material-components-ios

[my textfield](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhZxx.png)

How do I change the colour of MDCTextField's outline from purple to .systemBlue?

Answer (score 4):

this is a solution and work for me

```
let textField = MDCOutlinedTextField(frame: .zero)

textField.setOutlineColor( .black, for: .editing)
textField.setOutlineColor( .red , for: .disabled)
textField.setOutlineColor( .red , for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried?

```
let controller = MDCTextInputControllerOutlined(textInput: textInput)
controller.borderStrokeColor = .black
```